# HTML form field name and input field are not properly aligned against each other

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to create a form containing some fields to be filled by the user. The name of the field and its input field are not aligned perfectly against each other causing the user to face difficulty in filling the form as it creates confusion for which field the input box is for. I have even tried to put the form elements in a table but then it ruining the UI as the entire row completely contains the field name and the input box and it looks ugly. Herewith attaching the screen shot.[image]

```
<form action="http://203.115.101.30/kpmProcess/index.php/support/form_NewDeviceAddition" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <form data-toggle="validator" method="post"  name="myformlisting"  id="myformlisting" class="form form-horizontal" >
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <td colspan="2">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-control-2"  >Dispatch Date:*</label>
                  </td>
                  <td colspan="2">
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="datepicker1" value="" required />
                </div>
                  </td>
              </div>
        </tr>
        </table>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-control-3">Customer Name:*</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="customer_name" id="customer_name_id" required >
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-control-4">Truck No:*</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="truck_no" id="truck_no_id" required >
                </div>
              </div>
```

There are more fields and form tag is closed at the end.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: please share your code so we can check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a flexbox as a wrapper aligns them perfectly.

```css
input {
  padding: .5em;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.container:nth-child(1) label {
align-self: flex-end; /* vertical align bottom */
background: lightblue;
}

.container:nth-child(2) label {
align-self: center; /* vertical align center */
background: pink;
}

.container:nth-child(3) label {
align-self: flex-start; /* vertical align top */
background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label for="name">Customer name</label>
  <input name="name" type="text">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <label for="zip">ZIP code</label>
  <input name="zip" type="text">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <label for="place">Place</label>
  <input name="place" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: how can I center the label text vertically

Comment: Currently, the labels are vertically aligned in the center. I have adjusted the code so you can see how to align at the top or bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` should make the form more readable.